# How do you set a max ground height in a Minecraft customized map?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

How do you create a Custom world map in Minecraft, where everything is just like a normal map, but, the maximum ground height is 64. It should end up being pretty flat, but digging under the ground will be exactly the same as a normal map.

I don't want superflat, because (if I understand correctly) super flat doesn't give you the option to have everything underground be exactly the same as a normal map (you can fill it up with certain blocks at certain layers, but that's not what I want).

Answer (score 1):

you can use customised world generation in minecraft.

you need to change few values. I have marked them in the image below.

also note that, using customised generation, you will get good landscape but Position of structures like villages, strongholds,etc may or may not correspond to position generated by tool like chunkbase.

[image]

Comment: I've tried changing these values to "64" but these blocks still generate above 64.